# Problem Importing shapefile into postgresql with simple geometries

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, pgrouting

I have a Line Type shapefiles to be imported to postgis database on my postgresql, I'm using the SHP loader, I checked the "Generate simple geometries instead of MULTI Geometries" options so that the data will be routable. But it gives me an error message like this:

```
Importing with configuration: jalan_tangsel_test1, public, geom, C:\ms4w\apps\coba1\data\test1\jalan_tangsel_test1.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=1, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0 
Shapefile type: Arc
PostGIS type: LINESTRING[2]
We have a Multilinestring with 19 parts, can't use -S switch!
Shapefile import failed.
```

But if I unchecked the simple geometries options the shp import will be success, please help me

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your shapefile there is a MultiLineString you could open **jalan_tangsel_test1.shp** in a software like QGIS, for example. Then go to **Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to singleparts** menu and output **jalan_tangsel_test1_singleparts.shp**.

[image]

After that, you should be able to import **jalan_tangsel_test1_singleparts.shp** with the SHP loader, as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem time ago, I just ignored that message and everything has worked smooth since then. One thing I noticed, though, is when single and multi lines (ie. geometry) are merged together in one table. In that case you'd need to use:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom;
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK ((geometrytype(geom) = ANY (ARRAY['MULTILINESTRING'::text, 'LINESTRING'::text])) OR geom IS NULL);
```